# \pagestyle does not work as expected

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using the `fancyhdr` package and I have defined headers & footers for the `fancy` page style using the `fancypagestyle` command. I have also defined a new page style, `tocstyle`, using the same command.

Defined in this order:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}{%
    \def\footnotelayout{\color{darkgrey}}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % To change from all CAPS 
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}} % to normal case
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thechapter\ | \leftmark}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\textcolor{darkgrey}{Group 7}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\textcolor{darkgrey}{P2 Report - CPR Teacher}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thesection\ | \rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[RE]{\footnotesize{\thepage\ \textsl{of} \pageref{LastPage}}}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{\footnotesize{\thepage\ \textsl{of} \pageref{LastPage}}}
}

\fancypagestyle{tocstyle}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[RE]{\footnotesize{\thepage}}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{\footnotesize{\thepage}}
}
```

In the main .tex file I use the `tocstyle` for the `ToC` and then I change to `fancy`, but instead of applying the `fancy` style it looks like it has the `empty` style, the pages are completely empty.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,parskip=half-,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
    \begin{document}
        \pagestyle{tocstyle}
        \tableofcontents
        \clearpage
        \pagestyle{fancy}

        \include{baForeword}
        \include{bIntroduction}
        ...
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in

```
\pagestyle{fancy}{<your settings>}
```

The `\pagestyle` command requires only one argument, so the following text in braces is actually executed in a group and everything disappears after the closing brace.

```
\def\footnotelayout{\color{darkgrey}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % To change from all CAPS 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}} % to normal case

\fancypagestyle{bookstyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thechapter\ | \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textcolor{darkgrey}{Group 7}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textcolor{darkgrey}{P2 Report - CPR Teacher}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thesection\ | \rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\footnotesize{\thepage\ \textsl{of} \pageref{LastPage}}}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\footnotesize{\thepage\ \textsl{of} \pageref{LastPage}}}
}
\fancypagestyle{tocstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[RE]{\footnotesize{\thepage}}
  \fancyfoot[LO]{\footnotesize{\thepage}}
}
```

If you need to use the `tocstyle` page style for the table of contents, write something like

```
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
...
\pagestyle{tocstyle}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
%\cleardoublepage

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{bookstyle}

...
```

The `\cleardoublepage` should be added in order to mark precisely the transition between page styles; however, if `\mainmatter` immediately follows the table of contents pages, it's not necessary, because `\mainmatter` issues `\cleardoublepage` automatically.

It's better to define all the page styles necessary for the document, if one of them has to be used for more than one page (with `\thispagestyle`).

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. Now the `tocstyle` is applied to the whole document...

Comment: @benregn: If you declare `\pagestyle{tocstyle}` somewhere, this declaration has its effect until countermanded by another `\pagestyle` declaration or, if given in a group, until the group ends. I'll update my answer.